# why testing args.length?

Tags: java

I'm a Java beginner and I'm confused about testing args.length at the begining of many codes, and why it's never gets higher than 0 in any of my codes?

```
import java.net.Socket;
import java.net.UnknownHostException;
import java.io.IOException;

public class LowPortScanner {
public static void main(String[] args) {
String host = "localhost";
if (args.length > 0) {
host = args[0];
}
for (int i = 1; i < 1024; i++) {
try {
Socket s = new Socket(host, i);
System.out.println("There is a server on port " + i + " of "
+ host);
}
catch (UnknownHostException ex) {
System.err.println(ex);
break;
}
catch (IOException ex) {}
} // end for
} // end main
} // end PortScanner
```

Comment: Supply command-line arguments and the count will reliably rise.

Answer (score 1):

You have to inputs to `main` mathod from Command prompt.

like below

```
java LowPortScanner TEST1 TEST2
```

Answer (score 0):

Because if it is not tested then an exception would be thrown because `host = args[0];` would illegal.

However, this doesn't look like it's going to help much, an empty or `null` `host` looks like it would cause further problems.

If the length of `args` is always `0`, then be sure you're actually passing in parameter arguments.

Answer (score 0):

If there are no command arguments the `args[0]` will fail. This is why it must be protected.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how you invoke the Java class file. In command prompt or bash shell:

> java LowPortScanner Argument1

typing the above line in the command prompt/bash  will cause the argument count to increase to 1. (because `Argument1` is one argument, after the class file `LowPortScanner`)

> java LowPortScanner Argument1 Argument2

the above line will make argument count to increase to 2.

hence `args.length` will be `2` in the second case and `1` in the first case.

Answer (score 0):

If you are calling your program from CMD or bash you can asign ARGuments it like
`java LowPortScanner google.com`

Then "google.com" is your args[0]. When your program supports commandline attributes it is recommended to test if the given arguments are corret.

Answer (score 0):

`args` in `public static void main(String[] args` is the `String` array of arguments passed from command line.

`java LowPortScanner argument1 argument2`

if you try the above command `args.length` will return `2`.

As far as question of checking the length it is done for java programs which can take command line arguments and if arguments are not passed then they prompt for input.

```
if(args.length >0 ){
  //proceed using passed arguments
}else{
   //proceed with some default value
}
```

You are running your program using `java LowPortScanner` hence no arguments are passed and `args.length` is always zero.

Moreover if you don't pass any argument and use `host=args[0]` you will get `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`.

Comment: `prompt for input` is unnecessary, it will check localhost by default.

Comment: @Shayan_Aryan then you can upvote it and can accept it as your answer :)

Answer (score 0):

The variable String[] args hold all the parameter pass to the program thorough command line if you are not passing any argument then the length of args become 0. Now it's better to check it's length before accessing it other wise there is chance to get ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException if it's size is 0